# React Hook Form form submit is not working and getting redirected

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I am using React Hook Form and have 1 field. I want to validate that field (UI and service) and post successful validation, redirect user to Page2.

However, for some reason, I am getting redirected to http://localhost:3000/#/
I have event.preventDefault(), but still not sure why the redirect is happening to / and not to Page2

```
const {register, handleSubmit, trigger, setValue, getValues, formState, setError} = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(mySchema),
    mode: "onBlur",
    defaultValues: {name: ''}
});
const {errors, isValid} = formState;
const formRef = useRef();

const onSubmit = async (data, event) => {
    console.log('OnSubmit', data);
    event.preventDefault();
    await checkService(data);
    return false;
};

const checkService = async (data) => {
    const result = await ReactCall.post(url, payload);
    handleResponse(result); 
    if (result.data && result.data.errorFlag === false) {
        props.history.push("/Page2");
    }
}
    

<form ref={formRef} onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit, onError)}>
    <Input 
        {...register("name")} 
        inputProps={{maxLength: name.maxLength}}
    />
    <Button
        variant="cta"
        type="submit"
        disabled={!isValid}>
        Continue
    </Button>
</form>
```

Comment: first try to ```console.log(result)``` to check if you're getting the desired output that will trigger the ```if(result.data && ...)```

Comment: yes, i am getting the result